# jQuery: Event argument in anonymous function

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

```
 <div id="sampleDiv"></div> 
 var elObj = jQuery("#sampleDiv");
 var elObj = jQuery("#sampleDiv");

    function methodToExecute(event) {
        alert(event.touches[0].pageX);
       }

       elObj.bind('touchmove', function () {
           methodToExecute(event);
      }); // returns the pageX value but doesn't prevents the default behavior with event.preventDefault()

       elObj.bind('touchmove', function (event) {
           methodToExecute(event);
      });  // Prevents the default behavior with event.preventDefault() but throws error when trying to get pageX value, why ???
```

Which is the correct way to pass event argument in anonymous function so as to prevent the default browser behavior and to get the pageX and pageY values on touchmove event in touch devices ?

Answer (score 0):

```
elObj.bind('touchmove',function(event){
  methodToExecute(event);
});
```

EDIT: 
Hmm, you updated the question after I posted this